# Arreglar este algoritmo para que calculo el inverso

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer este algoritmo para calcular el inverso de un numero y ver si es capicua o no es. El codigo que tengo es este y no se como seguirlo, ayuda

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Numero_Capicua {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero;
        int auxiliar;
        int invertido = 0
        int cifra;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Introduce un número");                                                 
        numero = sc.nextInt();

        auxiliar = numero;
        do{
            // Como darle la vuelta asi ?? como saco la cifra ??
            invertido = invertido * 10 + cifra;
            auxiliar = auxiliar / 10;
        }while (auxiliar!=0)
        
        // Esto tengo que acerlo en una linea....
        if(numero == invertido){
            System.out.println("Es capicua");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No es capicua");
        }
    }
}
```

Comente lo que quiero hacer pero no lo consigo. Lo peor es lo ultimo que me piden en una linea. ayuda

Comment: ¿Y si lo manipulas como un String y no como un número?

Comment: es que me lo piden asi con numeros y queria conseguirlo asi ya

Comment: Para futuras preguntas, la idea es incluir en ellas qué errores encuentras. Al código que compartes le faltan varios `;` y eso da errores de compilación no relacionados con tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para sacar la cifra tienes que hacerlo calculando el módulo de la siguiente manera

```
cifra = auxiliar % 10;
```

Por otra parte, para mostrar en una línea el resultado, tienes que hacer uso del `if` ternario, quedando el código de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numero_Capicua {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero;
        int auxiliar;
        int invertido = 0;
        int cifra;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Introduce un número");                                                 
        numero = sc.nextInt();

        auxiliar = numero;

        do{
            cifra = auxiliar % 10;
            invertido = invertido * 10 + cifra;
            auxiliar = auxiliar / 10;
        }while (auxiliar!=0);
        
        System.out.println( numero == invertido ? "Es capicua" : "No es capicua");
    }
}
```

Te faltaban algunos `;` en tu código. Espero haberte ayudado !

Comment: Gracias me ha funcionado !!!